# USDt/Crypto payment gateway in the Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cryptography

in my lottery app, users can buy tickets by their usdt .when a user buy a ticket user's usdt transfer to the admin wallet. my problem is how can I integrate usdt payment gateway for my app

Comment: Could you find a solution for this? I am also want to do the same. If possible share the code.

Comment: are you find any solution? I am able to do with it coinbase commerce API. if you want I will share the project repository on GitHub

Comment: No still I couldn't.

Comment: I am able to do that with coinbase commerce API.refer this documentation (https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/commerce/docs/welcome) and this is my project that uses this API (https://github.com/danushaMalshan/lucky_touch.git)

Answer (score -3):

you can use a third party crypto payment gateway.
I suggest https://payid19.com for you, you create a request API and it will give you an link for redirect user for accepting usdt crypto.

Answer (score -3):

Try https://coinforbarter.com/. Third party crypto payment gateway. They have flutter plugin

https://plisio.net/. Third party crypto payment gateway. No flutter plugin